# Problema con Árbol binario

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Hola a todos ¡ Cómo están? Necesito imprimir un arbol binario en preorden pero ademas de imprimir los valores debo indicar si se ingresan por izquierda o derecha.
Seria algo asi:

Inserto en este orden:

- 10
- 7
- 9
- 20
- 15

Lo que debería imprimir es en ese mismo orden pero ademas debe decir si se ingreso por izquierda, por derecha y de que nodo. Sería algo así:

- 10 (raiz)
- 7 a la izquierda del nodo 10
- 9 a la derecha del nodo 7
- 20 a la derecha del nodo 10
- 15 a la izquierda del nodo 20

La verdad es que estoy perdida de como imprimir el texto y ademas citar el nodo que corresponda.

Mi codigo:

```
public class Arbolbinario {
    class Nodo
        {
            int info;
            Nodo izq, der;
            
        }
        Nodo raiz;
        String mensaje;
        int valor=0;
    
        
        
        public Arbolbinario() 
        {
            raiz=null;
        }
        
        public void insertar (int info)
        {
            Nodo nuevo;
            nuevo = new Nodo ();
            nuevo.info = info;
            nuevo.izq = null;
            nuevo.der = null;
            if (raiz == null)
            {
                raiz = nuevo;
            }
            else
                {
                Nodo anterior = null, reco;
                reco = raiz;
                
                while (reco != null)
                    
                    {
                        anterior = reco;
                        
                        if (info < reco.info)
                        {
                            reco = reco.izq;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reco = reco.der;
                        }
                    }
                
            if (info < anterior.info)
            {
                anterior.izq = nuevo;

            }
                else
                {
                  anterior.der = nuevo;
                }
                  }
                }
        
        private void imprimirEntre (Nodo reco)
            {
            
            
                if (reco != null)
                {
                    System.out.print(reco.info + " " + mensaje);
                    System.out.println ();
                    
                    imprimirEntre (reco.izq);
                    imprimirEntre (reco.der);
                }
            }
    
            
        
        public void imprimirEntre ()
            {
                imprimirEntre (raiz);
            
                
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Alguna idea para poder avanzar? Muy agradecida ¡¡

Answer (score 0):

Establece el valor del mensaje antes de llamar al método`imprimirEntre()`:

```
private void imprimirEntre(Nodo reco) {
    if (reco != null) {
        System.out.print(reco.info + " " + mensaje);
        System.out.println();
        mensaje = "a la izquierda de " + reco.info;
        imprimirEntre(reco.izq);
        mensaje = "a la derecha de " + reco.info;
        imprimirEntre(reco.der);
    }
}


public void imprimirEntre() {
    mensaje = "(Raiz)";
    imprimirEntre(raiz);
    System.out.println();
}
```